# Windows Large Page Support other than 2MB?

Tags: windows, paging, virtual-memory, huge-pages

I have read that the Intel chips support up to 1 GB virtual memory page sizes.  Using VirtualAlloc with MEM_LARGE_PAGES gets you 2MB pages.  Is there any way to get a different page size?  We are currently using Server 2008 R2, but are planning to upgrade to Server 2012.

Comment: The large page size is determined by the processor. On x86 with PAE enabled, the large page is 2MB. See Table 4-2 in the Intel System Architecture (volume 3A).

Comment: Is it possible to tell windows to use a specific size?

Comment: As I noted in the previous comment: Windows doesn't control the size. The processor controls the size.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look like it, the [Large Page Support docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) provide no mechanism for defining the size of the large pages. You're just required to make allocations that have a size (and alignment if explicitly requested) that are [multiples of the minimum large page size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I suppose it's theoretically possible that Windows could implement multiple large page sizes internally (the API function only tells you the minimum size), but they don't expose it at the API level. In practice, I'd expect diminishing returns for larger and larger pages; the overhead of TLB cache misses just won't matter as much when you're already reducing the TLB usage by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: No, Windows can't implement that. The thing is implemented in the CPU hardware: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)#Huge_pages

Comment: @Soonts: That reference makes it clear that some chips support multiple page sizes beyond a single default. I wasn't saying Windows could define arbitrary large page sizes purely in software, I was saying they could choose from the options available from the hardware; apologies if that was unclear.

Comment: Please note most chips on that table don’t run Windows. Only x86 and x86-64 chips do. On those chips, there’s simply no options to choose from, you either get 4MB pages in 32-bit mode without PAE, or 2MB pages otherwise.

Comment: @Soonts: Modern x86-64 in long mode supports 1 GB pages too. Not sure how practical that would be (I can't think of many scenarios outside the HPC space where 1 GB pages would make sense), but it's available.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Windows 10 (or 11 and later) it is finally possible to choose 1GB (as opposed to 2MB) pages to satisfy large allocations.

This is done by calling [VirtualAlloc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc2) with specific set of flags (you will need recent SDK for the constants):

```
MEM_EXTENDED_PARAMETER extended {};
extended.Type = MemExtendedParameterAttributeFlags;
extended.ULong64 = MEM_EXTENDED_PARAMETER_NONPAGED_HUGE;

VirtualAlloc2 (GetCurrentProcess (), NULL, size,
               MEM_LARGE_PAGES | MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT,
               PAGE_READWRITE, &extended, 1);
```

If the 1GB page(s) cannot be allocated, the function fails.

It might not be necessary to explicitly request 1GB pages if your software already uses 2MB ones.
Quoting Windows Internals, Part 1, 7th Edition:

> On Windows 10 version 1607 x64 and Server 2016 systems, large pages may also be mapped with huge pages, which are 1 GB in size. This is done automatically if the allocation size requested is larger than 1 GB, but it does not have to be a multiple of 1 GB. For example, an allocation of 1040 MB would result in using one huge page (1024 MB) plus 8 “normal” large pages (16 MB divided by 2 MB).

Side note:

Unfortunately the flags above only work for VirtualAlloc2, not for creating shared sections (CreateFileMapping2), where also new flag `SEC_HUGE_PAGES` exists, but always returns `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. But again, given the quote, Windows might be using 1GB pages transparently where appropriate anyway.